# How to redirect all stderr in bash?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I'm looking for a way to redirect all the stderr streams in interactive bash (ideally to its calling parent process).

I don't want to redirect stderr stream from each individual command, which I could do by appending `2> a_file` to each command.

By default, these stderr streams are redirected to the stdout of an interactive bash. I would like to get them on the stderr of this interactive bash process in order to prevent my stdout to be polluted by error messages and be able to treat them separatly.

Any ideas?

I still haven't found an answer ... But maybe it's actually a tty parameter. Does anybody knows something about tty/interactive shell responsibility for handling stderr ?

Comment: You mention python in a comment, could you show what code you're using to create these SSH streams. Are you not using popen/popen2/popen3?

Answer (score 10):

Use the `exec` builtin in bash:

`exec 2> /tmp/myfile`

Answer (score 4):

You could launch a new bash process redirecting the stderr of that process:

```
  $ bash -i 2> stderr.log
  $
```

Answer (score 3):

I find a good way is to surround the commands by parentheses, '()', (launch a sub-shell) or curly-braces, '{}' (no sub-shell; faster):

```
{
  cmd1
  cmd2
  ...
  cmdN
} 2> error.log
```

Of course, this can be done on 1 line:

```
{ cmd1; cmd2; ... cmdN; } 2> error.log
```

Answer (score 2):

Try your commands in doublequotes, like so:

```
ssh remotehost "command" 2>~/stderr
```

Tested on my local system using a nonexistant file on the remote host.

```
$ ssh remotehost "tail x;head x" 2>~/stderr
$ cat stderr 
tail: cannot open `x' for reading: No such file or directory
head: cannot open `x' for reading: No such file or directory
```

Comment: If you type the command directly after ssh, you aren't loading a shell on the remote host. Command is executed directly through the ssh channel.

I'm using paramiko in python but this is the same. 

My problem is that I need an interactive shell to execute many commands and still get stderr.

Answer (score 2):

I don't see your problem it works as designed:

```
$ ssh remotehost 'ls nosuchfile; ls /etc/passwd' >/tmp/stdout 2>/tmp/stderr 
$ cat /tmp/stdout  
/etc/passwd 
$ cat /tmp/stderr 
nosuchfile not found
```

Answer (score 2):

Two things:

1. Using `2>&1` in a remote ssh command results in the error ending up inside the local tarfile, resulting in a 'broken' backup.
2. If you want to apply a redirect on the other side of the ssh, remember to escape the redirect command.

My suggestion would be to redirect `stderr` on the remote side to a file and pick it up later, in case of an error.

example:

```
ssh -t remotehost tar -cf - /mnt/backup 2\>backup.err > localbackup.tar
EXITSTATUS=$?
if [ $EXITSTATUS != "0" ] then 
  echo Error occurred!
  ssh remotehost cat backup.err >localbackup.errors
  cat localbackup.errors
  ssh remotehost rm backup.err 
else 
  echo Backup completed successfully!
  ssh remotehost rm backup.err 
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

Tried `ssh -t` to create a pseudo-TTY at the remote end?